# Evolution Gmail Mashup + Fixing Time stamp

Tags: email, gmail, imap, evolution

I wanted to migrate my university email (including subfolders) to my gmail account.  Since gmail only imports POP3 which doesn't have subfolders, I had to connect to both gmail and my university mail using an email client (I am using Evolution) and then drag each folder from my university account to my gmail account.

This worked for the most part, but the time stamp on every email I dragged over from my university account to gmail reads as todays date, when it was dragged over.  If I enter the email and hit details it shows the actual sent date.  How can I get it to not overwrite the received date when transferring? (as I assume this is what is happening).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Gmail supports IMAP. if your university mail also supports IMAP, then try this:

1. Use Outlook Express or any other IMAP-capable desktop mail client.
2. Set up both your university mail as an account, and your Gmail, using IMAP.
3. Now you can drag-and-drop all university mail messages into Gmail.

   - If you use a mail client like Outlook, then you can even drag-and-drop entire folders, not just the messages inside. That should save you some time.

Comment: This is exactly what I did to get to where I am.  My problem is that some of the dates didn't transfer correctly.

Comment: That's how I did it, and it worked for me. That's a long time ago though -- something must have changed in the meantime.

Comment: But at your question Dan, you say that you used POP3 and not IMAP.